# SQL - Replace an integer value with a CHAR value

Tags: sql

I have a dataset showing the market cap of the stocks in my portfolio. When I run my query, I would like to replace the number with either Small , Mid or Large based on the size.
For Example, my API feed will show:

[image]

when market_cap is 0-9999 = replace with 'small', 1000-99999 = replace with 'Mid', 100000+ = replace with 'large"
Not sure how to put this into the query though.

Comment: Hint: look at the CASE WHEN statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` expression is obviously the way to go.  I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN Market_Cap < 1000 THEN 'Small'
             WHEN Market_Cap < 10000 THEN 'Mid'
             ELSE 'Large'        
        END)
FROM t;
```

This uses the fact that `case` condition stop at the first match, so `between` is not necessary.  This particularly construct assumes that `market_cap` is never `NULL` or negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case statement here:

```
SELECT 
    Ticker,
    Company,
    Sector,
    Industry,
    Country,
    Market_Cap,
    CASE 
        WHEN Market_Cap >= 0 AND Market_Cap <= 999 THEN 'Small'
        WHEN Market_Cap > 999 AND Market_Cap <= 9999 THEN 'Medium'
        WHEN Market_Cap > 9999 THEN 'Large'
    END
FROM 
    tblPortfolio
```

Comment: What if you have a `Market_Cap` value of 999.55 ?? The values shown by the OP aren't integer values - they're regular decimals - and your code doesn't handle that very well....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
*,
CASE 
WHEN Market_Cap BETWEEN 0 AND 999 THEN 'Small'
WHEN Market_Cap BETWEEN 1000 and 9999 THEN 'Mild'
WHEN Market_Cap >= 10000 THEN 'Large'        
ELSE 'no Market_Cap range assigned' END AS Category
FROM 
    [table name]
```